# How can I tell if InnoDB is ejecting pages?

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have a MySQL 5.5 RDS instance with 2tb SSD and 30gb RAM. Recently we have noticed that some specific queries which are backed by indexes are suddenly taking a huge amount of time (30+ seconds) and eventually timing out.

The query:

```
select
  count(distinct case when saletype = ? then sale.id end) as total_sales,
  sum(final_tax) as total_tax_amount,
  sum(final_total_ex_tax) as total_ex_tax_amount,
  sum(final_tax + final_total_ex_tax) as total_amount,
  max(final_tax + final_total_ex_tax) as best_sale
from platform_staff
join sale on sale.userid = platform_staff.id
join sale_lines on sale.numeric_id = sale_lines.sale_id
where ((platform_staff.merchant_id = ?)
  and (saledate between ? and ?))
  and (sale.site_id in ?))
```

The explain:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  sale    ref numeric_id_UNIQUE,fk_sale_user1,index_sale_site_id,index_sale_date  index_sale_site_id  5   const   172426  Using where
1   SIMPLE  platform_staff  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id_unique,fk_staff_merchant1    PRIMARY 108 kountadata001.sale.UserID   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  sale_lines  ref index_sale_line_sale_id index_sale_line_sale_id 4   kountadata001.sale.numeric_id   1   Using where
```

The interesting thing is that if I break the query up into pieces and run the the smaller queries several times it will eventually be able to perform the original query without timing out. Then I wait a few minutes and have to go through that process again.

This would suggest to me that pages are being ejected from memory shortly after being used, the buffer pool stats only tell so much:

```
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 24069734400; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 2156919
Buffer pool size   1435456
Free buffers       0
Database pages      
Old database pages 504601
Modified db pages  126657
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 11708661104, not young 0
788.62 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2360851192, created 69081262, written 4068758211
285.58 reads/s, 3.63 creates/s, 178.86 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 2 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 1367017, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[23143]:cur[9], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
```

It is possible to tell InnoDB to keep pages for specific tables in memory despite the read/write activity of other tables?

Comment: In the explain I think it should be saying "using where, using index" if the index is being taken advantage of.  I would say maybe you are not indexed on you where conditions.

Comment: @AldenW. that isn't what `Using index` means, but it's a common misconception.  The `Key` column not being null means that the index shown there was used.  `Using index` means that all the columns selected from the table are found in a single index, so the optimizer has decided to simply read those columns directly from that index, rather than using the primary key values from the index to look up row data from the main table data.  The index, in this case, is said to be a "covering index."  This capability is a very strong argument against using `SELECT *` when you don't actually need `*`.

Comment: When is your backup window, and is there any correlation?  I don't know how RDS does daily backups.  Using `mysqldump` is virtually guaranteed to cause evictions, but I've never observed evidence that RDS uses it.  Worth asking, though... maybe.

Comment: Please qualify each column with which table it belongs to.  (Preferably use aliases for brevity.)  Without that, we can't tell which tables have columns being summed; this is critical to optimization.

Comment: The short answer is simply "no".  But your real question has to do with performance?

Comment: Things like "pages read" is useless without knowing the `Uptime`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Ah, good to know. Thank you for the correction.